# CSS not working with a div under form why is it happening?

Tags: html, css

```
<form class="modal-content" id="bookingForm">

    <div class="formContainer">
      <div class="send" id="alert">
        Your Trip Has been Booked Sucessfully.
      </div>
      <h1>Booking Form</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to Book The Trip.</p>
```

I am trying to add css to the "send" class to make it appear with green background when the form is submitted.
The Css id given below:

```
.send{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

But The CSS is not working. What Is The Cause Of It??

Comment: Are you changing the display property of the send class to block when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write JavaScript to change the display property value from 'none' to 'block' once the button inside form is clicked.
Here's the full code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <form class="modal-content" id="bookingForm">

       <div class="formContainer">
           <div class="send" id="alert">
               Your Trip Has been Booked Sucessfully.
           </div>
           <h1>Booking Form</h1>
           <p>Please fill in this form to Book The Trip.</p>
       </div>
       <button>Submit</button>
   </form>
   <!-- <script src='./app.js'></script> -->
   <script>
       document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => showDiv(e));
       function showDiv(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           document.querySelector('.send').style.display = 'block';
       }
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Noe of the css Properties like text-align, padding, background, color are working. JavaScript is OK.

Comment: For me , it's working . Did you checked using Chrome Dev tools @BIJANROY ?